# Application of mean() and max() functions to some periodical rows and cols in R

Tags: r, mean

I have huge dataset like this from txt file:

```
DATE    TIME    B3M1    B3M2    B3M3    B3M4 ...
6 Nov 13    13:50:00    0   0   0   0
6 Nov 13    13:55:00    0   0   0   12
6 Nov 13    14:00:00    2   0   0   19
7 Nov 13    14:05:00    0   0   0   14
7 Nov 13    14:10:00    0   0   0   9
7 Nov 13    14:15:00    0   0   0   6
...
```

I need to find out `mean()` and `max()` values for each uniq `DATE` of every six data columns (B3M1:B3M6, B3F1:B3F6,...)(replications). How to do this?

Comment: Try reading `??plyr` and `?aggregate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the numerous options to do this, here's one using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean, max), -TIME)  # calculates mean and max for all columns except the grouping variable DATE and the excluded variable TIME by groups of DATE (1 row for each DATE)
```

Comment: I thought he wants a `mean` and `max` of every six columns... Have no idea what was the question

Comment: @AlexeyMoskalev since you accepted my answer, I assume it does what you were asking for. If not, please let me know, since the question was slightly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways. For example,Using `apply` function

```
Index <- which(data$DATE == specific date you want)
data <- data[Index,]
apply(data,2,mean)
```

Comment: Thank you koundy! The problem is that the dataset is really huge (>30000 rows) and I would be happy to escape date specification,  appling mean to any uniq date

Comment: oh ! didnt understood your question properly. Anyways `dplyr` solution @beginneR is perfect